# Add quantity to Ingredients

Tags: java, android, json, database, firebase

I want to make my database look **like this:**
[FirebaseDB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/juLlM.jpg)

I am adding ingredients' ingredientName from arrayList by looping them.

My question is how can I save easily quantity too. Measure will come from another DB path, when user added ingredientName
(for example "milk") to ListView.(but this is just a future plan, first I want to solve quantity)

Do I have to add EditText to list_item.xml ? Or how can I easily get quantity then save it?

**The ingredientName saving method works perfectly but I don't know how can I easily store quantity for each ingredientName.**

from AddIngredients activity:

```
private String key;
private ArrayList<String> arrayList=new ArrayList<>();
ListView listView=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.listv);
txtInput=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.IngredientsInput);
private DatabaseReference ingDBref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Ingredients");
private DatabaseReference DBref= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Recipes");

adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.list_item,R.id.ingredientName,arrayList);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);

public void addIngredients(){
        final String IngredientName=txtInput.getText().toString();

        ingDBref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot data: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    if(data.child("ingredientName").getValue().equals(IngredientName)){                        
            //If ingredientName=allowed ingredientNames from DB
                        arrayList.add(IngredientName);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            Toast.makeText(this,"Added to ListView...",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    else{
                    }
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }


public void saveIngredients(){
    key=DBref.child.push().getKey();
        String ingredientName;
        for(int i=0;i<arrayList.size();i++){
            ingredientName=arrayList.get(i);
            Ingredients ingredients=new Ingredients(ingredientName);
            DBref.child(key).child("Ingredients").child(ingredientName).setValue(ingredients);
        }
```

Ingredients Class:

```
public class Ingredients {

    String ingredientName;
   // String ingredientQty;
   // String measureName;

    public Ingredients(){
    }

    public Ingredients(String IngredientName){
        this.ingredientName=IngredientName;
       // this.ingredientQty=IngredientQty;
        //this.measureName=MeasureName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return super.toString();
    }

    public String getIngredientName(){
        return ingredientName;
    }
/*
    public String getIngredientQty(){
        return ingredientQty;
    }*/
    /*
    public String getMeasureName(){
        return measureName;
    }*/
}
```

list_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ingredientName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="24sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Could you please replace the image with plain text?

Answer (score 0):

```
-KvN3vdtkelmdlemakm33kml
    -Ingredients
        -milk
            -ingredientName: "milk"
            -measure: "dl"
            -quantity: "2"
        -sugar
            -ingredientName: "sugar"
            -measure: "g"
            -quantity: "50"
    -recipeDescription: "asd"
    -recipeID: "KvN3vdtkelmdlemakm33kml"
    -recipeName: "testRecipe"
```

The impoartant is under Ingredients.